# When running Virtualenv 1.6 on Mac OS X 10.6.7, Python 2.7.1

Tags: python, django, macos, virtualenv, python-2.7

I'm currently trying to set up pinax on top of Python 2.7.1 and Django 1.3.

For the first few steps, one is required to set up virtualenv, with the following commands:

> $ virtualenv mysite-env
>   $ source mysite-env/bin/activate
>   (mysite-env)$

I execute the first command, and it creates a mysite-env directory, but gives the following error:

> New python executable in mysite-env/bin/python
>   Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory while executing command install_name_tool -change /Library/Frameworks/.../Versions/2.7/Python @executable_path/../.Python mysite-env/bin/python
>   Could not call install_name_tool -- you must have Apple's development tools installed
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/virtualenv", line 8, in 
>       load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.6', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 745, in main
>       prompt=options.prompt)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 836, in create_environment
>       site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1098, in install_python
>       py_executable])
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 778, in call_subprocess
>       cwd=cwd, env=env)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 672, in __ init __
>       errread, errwrite)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1202, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception
>   OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Executing the second command does not work (this makes sense considering the first failed):

> bash: mysite-env/bin/activate: No such file or directory

I've read up on others that have had similar problems.

On another thread, someone [mentioned there's a bug with Virtualenv on 10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355188/problem-running-virtualenv-on-mac-os-x).

On google groups, another person offered a [patch for Virtualenv 1.3.3](http://groups.google.com/group/python-virtualenv/browse_thread/thread/17cab2f85da75951).

What is my best bet at this point? Should I install Virtualenv 1.3.3 and try the patch (I know it doesn't work for 1.6), or should I try to make it work with my current version? Is there an alternative to Virtualenv I could use (keep in mind I am contrained by the setup of pinax).

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> No such file or directory while executing command install_name_tool

install_name_tool command is a part of Mac OS X Developer Tools. Install Xcode to get it.